# how to add a pixelated and unpixelated effect to object

Tags: video

i want to create a video of having an object that becomes pixelated and unpixelated.
Like this: [image]

Comment: the easiest way is to use some effect in a video editor software after you render you cube  animation in blender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using **Pixelate** node in compositor.

As [official documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/filter/pixelate.html) notes, to create this effect you should put **Pixelate** node between 2 **Scale** nodes. And I add **value** and **math** node for manipulating this effect easily

[image]